# Is PWA Studio ready for production use?

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.4, graphql, pwa-studio

Going throught the demo store https://venia.magento.com/ and installing the headless version with our production instance it seems a lot of basic features are still msissing with PWA Studio provided by [Magento](https://magento.com) an [Adobe](https://adobe.com) company now.

They have it as a major highlight of their list of major features as well on Version 2.4.2. You'll be able to see this on this link: https://magento.com/products/new-releases

However it's very clear that the PWA implementation lacks a lot of features already present in the Luma theme. This project has been running since 2019 and it's very frustrating as an enterprise client that Magento teams asks us to go through a 3rd party agency to have a workable fully featured PWA website in production when we are paying tens of thousands of dollars a month on license fees.

**Putting up my question as a open discussion on PWA Studio and it's production readines.**

[image: Magento PWA Studio]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official roadmap https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/wiki/Roadmap for venia, still a lot to cover in order to have a fully functional production ready app, IMHO.

Comment: Does the M2 core have a roadmap?

Comment: @diana botean
Have you evaluated this again ?